# writing binary files with streams

Tags: f#

How to download image files via streams in the temp directory, I've following code and I'm stuck and need guidance with the seek and the count part. There are some wrapper approaches but I'm looking specifically for while loop approach for RAM efficiency reasons.

**Writing**

```
let tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName()

let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp "http://example.com/image.png"
use response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
use stream = response.GetResponseStream()

let buffer = Array.zeroCreate 1024
use reader = new BinaryReader(stream)

use memoryStream = new MemoryStream()
use fileStream = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Open)

while not (reader.PeekChar() <> -1) do
    fileStream.Write(reader.ReadBytes(1024), 0, 1024)

return Ok (tempFileName)
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? What "seek and count part" are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I notice that although you're creating a `buffer` array, you're not actually using it. Second, when I look at the [`BinaryReader` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx), and specifically the documentation for the [`ReadBytes` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), I notice that it takes an int parameter and returns a byte array. This must mean that it's *allocating a new array* every time, which seems to be the opposite of what you intend (since you mention RAM efficiency, I assume that what you actually want is to re-use the same buffer each time).

And one other observation: the ReadBytes method says that it might return an array smaller than the requested size, if there were fewer bytes available. Your code currently isn't handling that case.

All of these can be fixed, though, by switching to the [`BinaryReader.Read(byte[], int, int)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. With this method, your `while` loop would look something like the following:

```
while not (reader.PeekChar() <> -1) do
    let bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
```

And now that we're keeping track of how many bytes were read by each `Read` operation, we can get rid of the `PeekChar` call and save ourselves some time (calling `PeekChar` on something you're downloading is not without cost since the library has to download the next byte, then save it somewhere so it can be returned the next time you call `Read`). We can do that by checking how many bytes were read at the previous call: if it was 0, then that means we're at the end of the stream. To do this, we'll move the `bytesRead` variable out of the loop, which means making it a mutable variable that we'll re-use every time through the loop:

```
let mutable bytesRead = -1
while not (bytesRead = 0) do
    bytesRead <- reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
```

Or if you want to be slightly more explicit about the fact that you're skipping `Write` if bytesRead is 0, you could add an `if` block:

```
let mutable bytesRead = -1
while not (bytesRead = 0) do
    bytesRead <- reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
    if bytesRead > 0 then
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
```

That last `if` statement isn't strictly necessary, though: `FileStream.Write` should just return without doing anything if it's asked to write 0 bytes. However, since that's not documented anywhere that I could find, I added the `if` statement in this last code sample just to be on the safe side.

Comment: what I mean by RAM efficiency is those wrapper function reads the whole image data into memory and then writes to a file, that'd be inefficient for large images and several requests. By efficiency I mean write the chunk to the disk right away as it arrives/streams.

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 4.6.2, there is *System.IO.Stream#CopyTo* method:

```
namespace FSharpBasics

module ImageCrawler =

    open System.Net
    open System.IO
    open System.Text.RegularExpressions

    let private myurl = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/06/15/29/math-1500720_960_720.jpg"

    let crawler (url: string) =
        let fileName = Regex.Match(url, @"\/([^\/]+)$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups.[1].Value
        let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp url
        let response = request.GetResponse()
        use s = response.GetResponseStream()
        use w = File.Create fileName
        s.CopyTo w
        w.Flush true

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "JPEG file will be saved"
        crawler myurl
        printf "Saved"
        0
```